# How to sort and query DynamoDB by non unique values? I.E. Names

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Let's say I make a GSI for 'Name' and I have two people in my database who just happen to have the same name:

- Tim Cook
- Tim Cook

Now this will fail a consistency constraint on insert for duplicate values hence we need another approach.

I was thinking about hashing the name values at the end so that the `BEGINS_WITH` operator can still be used to search / match on but that puts you in a weird position. What do you salt with? How many characters? The longer the salt the more memory and potentially compute you waste cleaning up the salt before returning the results to the user. The shorter the salt the more likely you are to have collisions. After all there are some incredibly common names out there.

Here's an example of the values salted:

- Tim Cook#ABCDEF
- Tim Cook#ZYXWVU

This is great as I can insert both values now and now I can create a 'search user by name' endpoint for the user via the `BEGINS_WITH('Tim Cook')` operation but it feels weird.

I did a bit of searching though on sorting and searching by names in DynamoDB and didn't come up with anything meaningful on how to proceed from here. Wondering what you guys think.

My one and final issue is that names are not evenly spread out so you're inevitably going to have hotter partitions but I just don't see another way around this. Minus of course exfiltrating the data to another data store and querying it there like a full text search store.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t insert to a GSI. So your concern is kind of misplaced.

You also can’t Get Item on a GSI, only Query, and that’s because there’s not necessarily one matching value for a given key.

Note: The GSI always projects the primary key over from the base table.

Comment: This is all good information thank you. I'm just getting back into DynamoDB after a long break and I'm trying to work out any kinks in my design before I start implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following schema pattern to achieve your goal:

```
Partition key: Name 
Sort/Range key: createdAt (The creation time of that row)
```

In this case, if the name is same for more than 1 people, you will be returned with all the names sorted automatically. This schema will also allow you to create a unique access pattern for each item of your table.

```
Partition key -> Sort key
Name -> createdAt
Tim Cook -> "HH:mm:ss"
```

Each row will have a different creation time and will provide unique composite key values for each item of the table.

Comment: This is a cool approach however my partition key will have to be a UUID has I am pre-joining data and using a single table design. If I use mutable values for the partition key then I have to update the data everywhere it has been duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought GSI's had the same uniqueness constraint as partition keys however that's not the case - you can have duplicates.

> In a DynamoDB table, each key value must be unique. However, the key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique.
> [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.scenario)

So a GSI is a perfectly good way to store duplicated information. Not sure this question is helpful now since it came about through ignorance so it might be worth deleting now.